# Vimeo sound keeps playing in bootstrap modal after closing the modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vimeo

On this page we have multiple links to vimeo videos that all play in the same bootstrap modal, and populate the modal using data-src. The problem is that when the modal is closed the audio keeps playing. What script can I run to stop the audio playing?

The page is [here](http://www.objectiveconnect.com/) and you can see the video by clicking the image at the top that says "Secure File Sharing".

Comment: You should listen for the [`hidden.bs.modal` or `hide.bs.modal` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) and then in your event handler call whatever API Vimeo exposes to stop/pause/mute/destroy the video player.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I found that listening for the hidden.bs.modal event, didn't yield anything, instead `hide.bs.modal` worked for me.

Bonus - no need to hit the vimeo API

- You'll need to add an `id` to your iframe (in the example below, `id="iframe"`
- listen for the `hide.bs.modal` event
- capture the iframe src to a variable
- set the src to an empty string
- re-add the original src via the variable
  ...

  ```
     $('#orientation_video').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {

     // get the source of the iframe and save it
       var src = $(this).find('iframe').attr('src');

     // remove the src from the iframe
       $("iframe#iframe").attr('src','');

     // re-add the 
       $("iframe#iframe").attr('src', src);

     });
  ```